# Programmatically check the access to multiple cloud URLs with Azure AD auth token

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have listing page application which will load multiple cloud applications with Azure AD authentication enabled.

In my listing app, I have enabled oAuth and once the user authenticated, I am able to navigate the home page of accessible cloud applications.

But I need to filter the accessible cloud applications. 
I have tried to check the access programmatically by sending request with auth token.

Authentication got successes for both accessible and non-accessible url. But response string says sign in is needed. Please suggest me on this

Code to check the authentication

```
client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue( token.Key, token.Value );
try
{
    response = await client.SendAsync( request );
    if( response.IsSuccessStatusCode )
    {
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
} catch (){}
```